# Setting a variable inside Flask request using Middleware to be used inside templates

Tags: python, flask, wsgi

Based on the first part of the path an app is accessed from, I want the app to render differently. I tried setting a variable on the `request` using middleware and then accessing it in the template. I printed some debug information, which did show up so I know the middleware code ran, but the value wasn't set once I got to the template. How can I set a variable inside middleware that can be used in Flask?

```py
from werkzeug.wrappers import Request

class NavMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        request = Request(environ)
        print('path: %s, url: %s' % (request.path, request.url))
        
        if request.path.startswith("/myapp"):
            print("Here")
            request.application = "Myapp"
            environ['application'] = "Myapp"
        
        return self.app(environ, start_response)
```

```
{% if request.application == "Myapp" %}
    {% include 'navbar_myapp.html' %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `request` object you created in the middleware has no relation to the `request` object that Flask builds. Only the `environ` is passed between WSGI layers. The correct way for middleware to modify the request that subsequent layers see is to modify the `environ` dict. You've done that, so you need to access the value in `request.environ`, not on the `request` object itself.

```py
class NavMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, app, app_name):
        self.app = app
        self.app_name = app_name

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        request = Request(environ)
        first_path = request.path.lstrip("/").partition("/")[0]
        environ["nav_middleware.app_name"] = first_path
        return self.app(environ, start_response)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.wsgi_app = NavMiddleware(app.wsgi_app, "my_app")
```

```
{% if request.environ["nav_middleware.app_name"] == "my_app" %}
```

This answer applies to middleware in general, but in this particular case there's no need for middleware. WSGI servers can mount applications at different `SCRIPT_NAME` locations, which is exposed as `request.script_root`. You can simulate this in dev with Werkzeug's `DispatcherMiddleware`.

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
app.wsgi_app = DispatcherMiddleware(app, {"/one": app, "/two": app})
```

```
{% if request.script_root == "/one" %}
```